# Compile C++ file under linux

Tags: c++, linux, gcc

I am tring to compile and my C++ program on Linux  using gcc command.

I used `gcc -lm MyOwn.c Main.c -o Out`

`Myown.c` is another file I should link to the main.

The `Out` file is successfully created.

The problem is `Out` does not run.

When I tried to use gcc or cc to create exe file it gives me a lot of errors

Can someone help me?

Comment: What "does not run"?  What output do you get when you run your gcc command?

Comment: What's the output put of: *file Out*

Comment: By the way, if it really is C++ code, you should use g++ instead of gcc.

Comment: This is not a good question, since you provide no clue as to what the errors are.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
chmod +x Out
./Out
```

Comment: Correct, but sometimes things happen when one fiddles with files :)

Answer (score 2):

The question is tagged C++.  You say you're new c++.  But the example you gave involve c code only.

gcc is used to compile c programs.
Use g++ instead.

C++ code files should have the suffix `.cpp` or `.c++`, but never `.c`.

Fix those, try again, and edit the question to add the command line error if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Sometimes, also .C (uppercase C) is used (which is recognized by g++), although it's not recommended, since it's not portable on case-insensitive systems (and it's also more difficult to catch at glance).

Comment: I purposely omitted `.C`.  It's about as useful as a trigraph.  Though `.cc` is common enough.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem may be that you're compiling as C code.  Your files end with a ".c", and you are invoking `gcc`.  You should end the file name with ".cpp" or ".cc" or ".c++" or something else the compiler will recognize as C++.

You can also compile as C++ explicitly by typing `g++` instead of `gcc`.